# HTML Display boxes when option is checked

Tags: html, css

I need help for an upcoming assignment, I am creating a website but I am currently stuck on the Products Page

I've made a dropdown box selection and I'd like to display a box containing information about the product with a button to "purchase" ( the purchase button doesn't have to work ) but I am having troubles doing this

here is the current code:

```
<div class="category">
        <label class="pcpartstext" for="pcparts">Choose a category:</label>
            <select name="pcparts" id="pcparts">
                <optgroup label="Computer Hardware">
                    <option value="cpu">Central Processing Unit (CPU)</option>
                    <option value="cpucooler">CPU Cooler</option>
                    <option value="mobo">Motherboard</option>
                    <option value="ram">Random Access Memory (RAM)</option>
                    <option value="storage">Storage (HDDs/SSDs)</option>
                    <option value="gpu">Video Cards (GPU)</option>
                    <option value="psu">Power Supply (PSU)</option>
                    <option value="cases">Case/Chassis</option>
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup label="Computer Accessories">
                    <option value="monitor">Monitors</option>
                    <option value="keyboardmousepad">Keyboard, Mouse & Mousepads</option>
                    <option value="speakerandheadset">Speakers & Headsets</option>
                </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Please if anybody can help, I would appreciate it a lot !! Thankss

Comment: Just to clarify you want to use jQuery to get this done or JS ? Or anything will do.

Comment: I would prefer any method that is easy to understand, thank you!

Comment: See my answer. You can do the same for each option just like i did for first two option when i select from the drop down.  Just add the info to each of `if else` product as you want. Just run the snippet to see results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code for you. You can do some styling to it as you want.

You can do the same for each option just like i did for first two option when i select from the drop down. Just add the info to each of if else product as you want.

```js
$('#pcparts').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === 'cpu') {
    $('.prodct-info').html('<div class="details"><p class="info">CPU product info</p><button class="purchase">Purchase</button><div>')
  } else if (this.value === 'cpucooler') {
    $('.prodct-info').html('<div class="details"><p class="info">CPU Cooler product info</p><button class="purchase">Purchase</button><div>')
  }
});
```

```css
.details {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category">
  <label class="pcpartstext" for="pcparts">Choose a category:</label>
  <select name="pcparts" id="pcparts">
    <optgroup label="Computer Hardware">
      <option selected disabled>Choose One</option>
      <option value="cpu">Central Processing Unit (CPU)</option>
      <option value="cpucooler">CPU Cooler</option>
      <option value="mobo">Motherboard</option>
      <option value="ram">Random Access Memory (RAM)</option>
      <option value="storage">Storage (HDDs/SSDs)</option>
      <option value="gpu">Video Cards (GPU)</option>
      <option value="psu">Power Supply (PSU)</option>
      <option value="cases">Case/Chassis</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Computer Accessories">
      <option value="monitor">Monitors</option>
      <option value="keyboardmousepad">Keyboard, Mouse & Mousepads</option>
      <option value="speakerandheadset">Speakers & Headsets</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="prodct-info">
  <div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a quick question, sorry for my noobiness, the first bit of code with the dollar sign, do I add that in a .js file ?

Comment: @KuntaKinte yes you can add this in your JS file or have it your same html file. By Adding the <script> js code in between here </script> and your should be good. Please accept this answer as well and upvote so it helps others as well. Thanks

Comment: I added it as a JS file but when I select the the CPU or CPU cooler nothing displays on the screen.

Also upvoted :)

Comment: @KuntaKinte Okay you need to reference your JS file in the head (top) of your HTML file like this: `<script src="file.js"></script>` This will load the script when your HTML page loads and dropdown will work just fine.

Comment: @KuntaKinte Thanks. Glad that i can help.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this ? Really sorry about the bump, need this urgently

Comment: @KuntaKinte Just making sure you have added jQuery script `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  in your HTML page as well ? Also check the chrome dev tools by clicking F12 and go to console and see what the errors are to fix them.

Comment: Yes I have added the script and console spits out no errors

Comment: Can you share your code or project online. I do not see a reason why it not working. Just the exact code above. JS and HTML put it all in file and run it. Should run all fine just like above.

Comment: Here you go I added a github link to make life easier:


https://github.com/unitdogg/website_dev

Comment: @KuntaKinte i have added file called working_file.html just pull it from github.

Comment: Omg!!! Thank you so much :) It works flawlessly now. I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: @KuntaKinte All good. Best of luck and please upvote this answer as well by clicking the grey tick box next to the answer. Cheers.